# Ionic2 with MaterializeCSS

Tags: angular, ionic2, materialize

I will use Ionic2 with MaterializeCSS but I don't know how. I install angular2-materialize and material-css and try to import.

I try to add css and js via index.html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css" />
```

If I use this, its work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Some ideas?

Comment: you can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize) .

Answer (score 0):

You can not refer any static  files from node_modules or any other directory outside www.
 because  www(v1) or src(v2) directory  is going to go inside mobile App.
you just think yourself , is it practical to stuff node_module also inside App?